# How to set old value for SELECT tag in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**create.blade.php**

```
<select  id="category" class="form-control" name="category"  required>
<option selected disabled>- Select -</option>
<option {{ old('category') == $key ? "selected" : "" }} value="{{ $value }}">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

> Error : Undefined variable: key (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelCrud_x\resources\views\create.blade.php)

Comment: Where does you `$value` and `$key` comes from?? You are not iterating over an array to have that.

Comment: in your code where are come from $key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where do your variables come from, but the error is pretty obvious, you don't have those variables defined anywhere in order to use them.. old value works the way you use it, but it should be with real data, for example for your other fields you can do this:

```
<option value="A" @if(old('category') === 'A') selected @endif>A</option>
<option value="B" @if(old('category') === 'B') selected @endif>B</option>
<option value="C" @if(old('category') === 'C') selected @endif>C</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ans almost right only need to remove $key from this code or send this from controller

```
<select  id="category" class="form-control" name="category"  required>
    <option selected disabled>- Select -</option>
    <option {{ old('category') == "A"? "selected" : "" }} value="A">
    <option {{ old('category') == "B"? "selected" : "" }} value="B">
    <option {{ old('category') == "C"? "selected" : "" }} value="C">
</select>
```

If you use array key value this code will be different

Answer (score 0):

```php
<select name="category">
  <option value="">Select a category</option>
  <option value="1" {{ old('category', $post->category_id) == '1' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Category 1</option>
  <option value="2" {{ old('category', $post->category_id) == '2' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Category 2</option>
  <option value="3" {{ old('category', $post->category_id) == '3' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Category 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if use [@selected](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#additional-attributes) directive in Laravel Blade

```
<select name="category">
    <option>Select a category</option>
    <option value="catX" @selected( old('category') == 'catX' )> Category_X </option>
    <option value="catY" @selected( old('category') == 'catY' )> Category_Y </option>
    <option value="catZ" @selected( old('category') == 'catZ' )> Category_Z </option>
</select>
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php) [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)